# Extbase: scheduler cannot load a class

Tags: scheduled-tasks, scheduler, extbase, autoloader

I have a scheduler (extension "scheduler" 6.2.0) task class:

```
namespace MyVendor\MyExt\Scheduler;
class MultiStepProcessTask extends \TYPO3\CMS\Scheduler\Task\AbstractTask {
  public function execute() {
    $objectManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Object\\ObjectManager');
    $businessLogic = $objectManager->get(\MyVendor\MyExt\Scheduler\MultiStepProcessTaskBusinessLogic::class);
    return $businessLogic->run();
  }
}
```

And a class implementing business logic for the scheduler task:

```
namespace MyVendor\MyExt\Scheduler;
class MultiStepProcessTaskBusinessLogic {
  public function run() {
    ...
  }
}
```

I created a scheduler task in BE. If I run it manually - it's OK. If it is started automatically - following error message comes:

> [scheduler]: Task failed to execute successfully.    Class:
>   MyVendor\MyExt\Scheduler\MultiStepProcessTask,   UID: 8. Could not
>   analyse class:
>   MyVendor\MyExt\Scheduler\MultiStepProcessTaskBusinessLogic   maybe not
>   loaded or no autoloader? (msg#4.0.255)

The best is - after being once run manually, the task runs automatically without errors until the cache is cleared. After that it needs one manual run again.

One more strange thing: in the main scheduler task class (`MultiStepProcessTask`) no injection is possible. That's why I had to create business logic object via objectManager

Comment: If its a problem with the class name cache, maybe add the class manually to ext_autoload.php will help?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be to write a command controller based on extbase. There you can use the `ObjectManager` and you can run it directly from CLI and of course also call it via scheduler!

Comment: You mean implement business logic not in a _scheduler_ task, but in something independent? Do you have an example of such solution? How can such a controller be started? I've thought _controller_ always fills a _view_ and in this case there will be no _view_.

Comment: You can take a look at the docs: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/10-Outlook/3-Command-controllers.html

And of course, there is no view but you can fully interact with it via CLI as since 7.x the symfony commands are available as well

Comment: As far as I know, and as far as the documentation goes, this is available only from 7.x, he's on a 6.2 system.

Comment: @Georg Ringer: Yes, I'm on 6.2. But I think if `ObjectManager` cannot load my class with business logic in the context of _scheduler task_, it also won't be able to load it in the context of command controller started from the context of a _scheduler task_.